# Validation in Update Panel within a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, updatepanel, repeater

I am using an Update Panel within a Repeater. I need for the Update Panel to contain validation. The validation is in place but is getting fired for each Panel. I need it to only be applied to the Panel being accessed.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" 
    runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="rptComments_OnItemDataBound" 
    OnItemCommand="rptComments_OnItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul class="comments">
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelReply" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcForm" runat="server">
                                <div class="errors">
                                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="nestedCommentsValidation" ValidationGroup="nestedSubmit" runat="server" cssClass="validation" ForeColor="Red" />
                                </div>

                                <label>Name<sup>*</sup></label> 
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbReplyName" runat="server" cssClass="styledInput"></asp:TextBox><br />

                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_tbReplyName" 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    Display="None"
                                    ControlToValidate="tbReplyName" 
                                    InitialValue=""
                                    ErrorMessage="Please enter your name."
                                    ValidationGroup="nestedSubmit">
                                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="submit-button" CommandName="SubmitReply" ValidationGroup="nestedSubmit" />
                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                 </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking out the validation group and handling it in the OnItemCommand event. There may be a slicker way of doing it, but this worked for me.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbReplyName.Text.ToString().Trim()))
            strValidationMessage = "<li>Please enter your name.</li>";

Literal ltrErrorMessage = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrErrorMessage");
            ltrErrorMessage.Text = strValidationMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using different validation groups in your different panels?  The whole point of the validation group is that the validators will only validate the controls that are in the same group.

Comment: I'm not setting anything on the ItemDataBound within the repeater to differentiate the validation groups. What you see in the code posted is all I have regarding the validation.

I should point out that the form submits on the update panels work fine. It's really just the validation I can't differentiate between the panels.

Comment: As mentioned above by the user above, you should be setting the validatiation group to distict values in the rptComments_OnItemDataBound event to get the validations to work properly

Comment: Right, I understand that. But I'm looking for help on the syntax.

Comment: You should be able to set the Validation Group to a dynamic value every time you go through the repeater.  Try something like

ValidationGroup="nestedSubmit" + the id field from your repeater data source.

the ValidationGroup is just a string so you should be able to concatenate